# Time reversal in GR

Tags: general-relativity, time

Watching Lenny Susskind's GR lectures, I was I interested by the question of whether a black hole could grow if it took for ever for a mass to fall in viewed from outside. The answer, as I understand it,  is that's a limit for a very small I falling mass. For a finite mass the black hole will bulge swallow it and settle down. My question is do the equations make sense with the film run backwards? In other words could a black hole spit something out? Presumably not and I imagine it's got to do with an entropy arguement but How? Similarly on all this talk of colliding black homes and gravity waves. Could a black hole be disrupted by incoming gravity waves? Please keep it simple as I'm just an amateur.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hole